# Retrieving a shared preference inside a baseexpandablelistadapter

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm writing a baseexpandablelistadapter. Inside of it, I'd like to execute an sqlite query, for which I need a string to pass as a search parameter. I've stored this string in a shared preference, and now I want to retrieve it. Unfortunately, I seem to be unable to do this.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ClientSmartFinderSettings child = (ClientSmartFinderSettings) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }       

        try {
            //this is where the error is
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);

            holder.checkBox.setChecked(child.getIsSelected());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


        return view;
    }
```

The error is:

> MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable

I understand that MODE_PRIVATE seems only to be applicable to an Activity. But how then do I retrieve this shared preference inside of my baseexpandablelistadapter?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that. It just changes the error to "The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type ExpandListAdapter"

Comment: You have to give a Context param in your Adapter's constructor and use it as `mContext.getSharedPreferences(String, int);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, it's not a good practice to execute queries while creating and binding views in an AdapterView, but to answer your question:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("FileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

also, I would create the SharedPreferences object just once in the constructor of your Adapter class (you can pass a Context object there). This wil remove scrolling hickups.

Comment: I agree about this not being a good idea, but it's the best idea that I have at the moment. We'll see if it pans out. I used your suggestion to do this inside the constructor. That solved much of my problem. The final line (inside the constructor) that I used is: "sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("FileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);" Thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW, I found out how to accomplish this without retrieving the shared preference inside of the adapter, per your advice. I didn't realize what the adapter was capable of doing, so now I understand its purpose much better. +1 for that advice. It made me think a little harder. Thanks again!